# Self-incrementaI item ID logic

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'll try to explain my problem as simply as I can. I am developing a server for an app that helps police officers to mark citizens' property.

Every new item has it's own Id. It consists of officer's district Id (two-didgit), 5 self-incremental digits and a current year. For example: 20-00001-18.

To assign district Id and a current year is easy, but I don't know right way to create 5 digit number. This number is district dependant and resets every year. My idea was to create seperate table in database that would keep the record of past item's id but I don't think that it's the best way to do it.

Do you have any ideas how to do it the best way possible?

Comment: different databases have different facilities for doing this. Since you tagged your question with mongodb, have a look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Mongo Sequence in a separate collection `mycounters`

```
db.mycounters.insert({ _id: "mySeq", seq: 0 })
```

Then define a `function` to read the next value from the defined sequence

```
function getNextMySeq(name) {
   var ret = db.mycounters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```

You can now use the function `getNextMySeq` in you insert query to generate `_id`.
Remember you can concatenate the sequence with other parts of your keys like below

```
db.c.insert({_id:'20' + getNextMySeq("mySeq") + '2018', name: 'aa'})
```

In my `insert` query `20` & `2018` are hardcoded but you can actually have variables when you programatically prepare the insert.